# Fisher information and score

Tags: statistics, estimation, log-likelihood, fisher-information

We know that the Fisher information for a probability density function $f_{{\theta}}(\textbf{X})$ with a given true value of the parameter ${\theta}$ and an observable random variable $\textbf{X}$ is given by

\begin{equation}
{\small
\begin{split}
I(\theta) = E\left[\left(\frac{\partial \ln f_{{\theta}}(\textbf{X})}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right]=
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\frac{\partial \ln f_{{\theta}}(\textbf{X}^i)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2 \label{fishinfo}
\end{split}
}
\end{equation}
Score is given by
$\frac{\partial \ln f_{{\theta}}(\textbf{X})}{\partial \theta}$. At the true value of $\theta$, $\frac{\partial \ln f_{{\theta}}(\textbf{X})}{\partial \theta}=0$, am I rite in saying this?

If this is true how is $I(\theta)$ not zero? I am unable to understand the concept here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not the definition of Fisher information, which is variance of score function. Expectation of score is zero, not score itself.

Comment: In MLE we equate the mean of the score to zero to obtain the parameter that maximizes the likelihood rite?

Comment: You equate the score to zero while finding MLE. So? MLE does not come into play in the definition of Fisher information.

Comment: I want to calculate fisher information at a point where score is zero (MLE). If this MLE happens to give the true parameter then  the curvature at that point is the fisher info rite? I think I understand now. Expectation of score is zero not just the score.